# What is significant account-specific functionality from Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, app-store, appstore-approval

My Application got rejected from appstore by saying that **"your app must include significant account-specific functionality from Facebook"** i am using Facebook login and also Facebook sharing. In my app i have two type of login 
1: Facebook login
2: Guest Login
 Some functionality in my app is restricted for Guest user that can only perform if you login with Facebook.

Can any one please tell me that what is account-specific functionality from Facebook?
Did Any body have phase this issue and if they got solution please share.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32232914/ios-application-using-facebook-rejected

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use Facebook log in, apple wants you to use significant account-specific functionality. This means that you should use things from Facebook like user interest or friend list. Using the user name profile pictures are not considered account specific functionality. Apple is saying if you are not using these information then you are not supposed to use Facebook authentication.

You have 2 solutions here:

1. Use the significant account-specific functionality from Facebook ex. interests or friend list.
2. Apple will accept the use Facebook log in without significant account-specific functionality if you also add your own login and password.

I am sure of this information because I got it from apple review team member today!

Answer (score 0):

At last i have successfully published my App without too much of changes.

if you have only Facebook Login then you need to add guest login or skip button.So that users who do not have Facebook account they can also enter in your App.Because if some of users do not have Facebook account then they can not use or see your App.

Once guest user navigated to Home screen or main Screen then you can restrict some of the feature that guest user can not perform. if user click on that show some popup by saying **message** that "Guest user can not use this feature.Do you want to move to Login Screen" if user click on "Yes" move to login Screen If "No" then remove popup and what ever **message you want you can give**.**But Do not give any message which force user to login to Facebook**.

*But in the same time if you are going to publish your app then you have to clearly mention in note that why guest user can not perform and what is the use of Facebook login what functionality you are using by Facebook, if user is not login with Facebook how it will effect this feature.
What i understood by significant account-specific functionality from Facebook is that if some feature is restricted for guest user and that can be performed only by Facebook login user then what is the use of Facebook in that feature and if there is no use of Facebook then it should not be restricted and guest user also can use this feature.*

Wish you all the best